# What could possibly cause a Linux "ls" command to return a seg fault?

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault

I am installing some new software.  It contains several libraries in a "Lib" directory.  If I `ls Lib` from *another* directory, I get the usual list of files.  I can issue `dir` and `file` commands and get reasonable results too.  I can even copy files out of this directory to other directories.  But if I cd to "Lib", it appears that *any* linux command I give returns a seg fault.  I can't run `ls`, `file`, or `dir` in that directory.  I can't even run `date` there without a seg fault.  Much obliged if anyone can help me clear up this mystery.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably your [LD_LIBRARY_PATH](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) includes a dot / `.` and that `Lib` directory contains standard libraries like libc, so what ever command you issue, system picks a library from that path and something goes wrong.

Comment: Dang!  Not bad!  Adding "." to LD_LIBRARY_PATH was part of the installation instructions and, yes, `Lib` does have a libc.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On my rpi I observed today the same issue:

```
$ ls
Segmentation fault
```

What it solved for me was:

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem after downloading and building libc separately.
I opened a new terminal and confirmed that it worked properly after `$unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.